# How to hack proof a data submission program

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography

I am writing a score submission system for games where I need to ensure that reports back to the server are not falsified (aka, hacked).

I know that I can store a password or private passkey in the program to authenticate or encrypt the request but if the program is decompiled, a crafty hacker can extract the password/passkey and use it to falsify reports.

Does a perfect solution exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All you can do is make it difficult for cheaters.

You don't say what environment you're running on, but it sounds like you're trying to solve a code authentication problem*: knowing that the code that is executing is actually what you think it is. This is a problem that has plagued online games forever and does not have a good solution.

Common ways in which such systems are commonly broken:

- Capture, modification and replay of submissions to the server
- Modifying the binary to allow cheating
- Using a debugger to modify the submission in-memory before the program applies signatures/encryption/whatever

Punkbuster is an example of a system which attempts to solve some of these problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PunkBuster

Also consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_online_games

Chances are, this is probably too hard for your game. Hiding a public key in your binary and signing everything that leaves it will probably put you well ahead of the pack, security-wise.

* Apologies, I don't actually remember what the formal name for this is. I keep thinking "running code authentication", but Google comes up with nothing for the term.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you can do - record all of the user inputs and send those to the server as part of the submission.  The server can then replay the inputs through a local copy of the game engine to determine the score.  Obviously this isn't appropriate for every type of game, though.  Depending on the game, you may need to include replay protection.

---

Another method that may be appropriate for *some* types of games is to include a video recording of the high-scoring play within the submission.  Provide links to the videos from the high score table, along with a link to report suspicious entries.  This will let you "crowd-source" cheat detection - if a cheater's score hits the table at number 1, then the players behind scores 2 through 10 have a pretty big incentive to validate the video for you.  If a score is reported enough times, you can check the video yourself and decide if it should be removed (and the user banned).

Comment: Hmm... that's pretty clever. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the best you'll get. Bots or computer assisted players are still possible though. And there is the technical problem that for this kind of replay to work the game needs to be deterministic. For example there can be problems with floating-point rounding or iteration over certain unordered containers. And of course multi-threading can lead to indeterminism even with correct locking.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: This is true.  You will have to be careful to ensure the game is deterministic (given the same initial seed), which may be tricky depending on how you use threads.

Comment: Making the PRNG deterministic is the smallest problem. It jitted languages the jitter can generate either x87 or SSE instructions, which yield different results(or do some other optimizations influencing the result). And for example in C# the order in which elements are returned when iterating over a `Dictionary` or `HashSet` is undefined.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Agreed.  The iterator problem seems surmountable (ensure the final outcome of the code doesn't depend on the element order).  The floating point one is trickier.

Comment: Ensuring that the final outcome is order independent is hard since so many operations do not commute. For example with floating-point a+b+c isn't the same as b+c+a. I'd rather use my own containers with defined iteration order. It seems to be possible to prevent the floating-point problem in C++, but close to impossible in C#/.net. For my own project I'll probably use fixed-point instead, but that's a *big pain*.